# How to change the text of the RDP title bar?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I would like to change the text of the RDP title bar. I wonder if there is a way to do that from within the file setting?

For example if you edit an RDP file with notepad and add

```
full address:s:127.99.99.99:12850
```

when you click on the RDP file the destination IP will be 127.99.99.99:12850.
Is there something for the text in the title bar?

I'm aware it uses the file name in the title

Comment: This question has an interesting work around to do this: https://superuser.com/questions/236208/how-do-i-get-user-friendly-names-in-remote-desktop

Answer (score 2):

You could use Remote Desktop Plus ( http://www.donkz.nl) which allows you to use a `/title` argument to change the window title.